# Obj-C autorelease network request released before completing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, autorelease

I have a wrapper class that is built around a network request. 
lets call it 'WrapperNetworkRequest'

The reason I wrap it is because I process the JSON response once it comes back.
Then using the 'WrapperNetworkRequestDelegate' protocol, return the response to the delegate.

The problem I am having is that when using the 'WrapperNetworkRequest' class as an autoreleased object, it auto-releases before the network request can complete.

I came up with what I think is a horrible idea ([self retain]+[self release] at the appropriate times)

Any ideas on what is a proper way to handle this/What I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: First, @sho provides a good solution and this is usually the best way. Second, `[self retain]` has a long history. You're hardly the first to use this technique :D (I'm not defending it; just saying I've seen it many times, and used it a few times.) Third, you may want to consider a framework like MKNetworkKit that is designed to handle this problem (and related problems) and automatically manages its own queue. You can also look at how it keeps its connections alive for inspiration. https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retaining `self` is a perfectly sane idea when you have to extend the object's lifetime. How exactly you do that is another matter: you can do `[self retain]` or you can add `self` to a shared retaining array keeping all objects of the given kind. Think `NSOperationQueue`. After you add an operation object to a queue, you can safely release the operation because by adding it to the queue you've transferred ownership of the operation to the queue.

Comment: although @sho provided an answer that partially solves my issue, this seems to be the solution for my needs. After reading your answer and doing some research, I found some literature suggesting an NSURLConnection for example add's itself to to the run loop, which take ownership of it until it completes. This permits greater flexibility within classes that would like to use the wrapper class as a local variable. Having the wrapper class add it self to a shared instance which takes ownership until the wrapper finishes seems to make more sense for my situation. Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having your `WrapperNetworkRequest` retain itself in its `NSURLConnectionDelegate` implementation methods, have its delegate assume ownership. One possible way to do this:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject <WrapperNetworkRequestDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, retain) WrapperNetworkRequest * wrappedRequest;

@end

@implementation Foo
@synthesize wrappedRequest;

//....

- (void)bar
{
    WrapperNetworkRequest * request = [WrapperNetworkRequest aNewAutoreleasedRequest];
    request.delegate = self;
    self.wrappedRequest = request; // Foo instance assumes ownership

    [request goGetData];
}

//....

@end
```

Comment: Thanks. I have considered this approach, but I still wonder, what if I were to give this wrapper class to a friend? Would i have to tell them that the only _italic_ guaranteed _italic_ way to get a response is by retaining it.

Comment: I have been struggling with this same problem and my solution is the same as here - i.e. you have to as a caller ensure that the object stays around. If you think about it, it makes sense as well. If the object using the request doesn't own it then how can it guarantee it'll ever get anything back from it?

Comment: Something needs to handle the response, right? It would seem appropriate that the handler (i.e. the delegate) accept ownership of (i.e. retain) the request.